# Proper PDO syntax for parameterized query using LIKE with wildcards (ex %, _)

Tags: php, mysql

The following syntax is the current syntax I have that's works.

```
$dbh = connect();
$singer = strtolower($_GET["singer"]);

$SQL =
      "SELECT *
        FROM table
        WHERE field1 LIKE ?
        ORDER BY field2 ASC";

$sth = $dbh-> prepare ($SQL);
$sth->bindParam (1, $singer);
$sth->execute();
```

What changes do I need to make to the line of code `WHERE field1 LIKE ?` to perform the query with the wildcard `%`?

I've tried `WHERE field1 LIKE '%?%'` but that didn't work.

Do I have to prepend `'%`

and append `%'`

to the value stored in `$singer`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TRY

```
$str = "%".$singer."%";
$SQL =
      "SELECT *
        FROM table
        WHERE field1 LIKE ?
        ORDER BY field2 ASC";

$sth = $dbh-> prepare ($SQL);
$sth->bindParam (1, $str);
```

[Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) ==> see 3rd Example