# PHP parameterized on mysql query with LIKE and CONCAT on partial string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm struggling with this query. I'm trying to match one of two fields against a partial string for an ajax call. Start typing a name, it should match against first or last name.

My parameterized query is returning 0 rows on LIKE statement.

I've tried answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583336/how-do-i-create-a-pdo-parameterized-query-with-a-like-statement) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482147/sql-parameterized-query-with-like-php) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138807/proper-pdo-syntax-for-parameterized-query-using-like-with-wildcards-ex).

I'm afraid I'm missing something simple, but I can only think that the parameters aren't passing in right for the partial string.

```
<? 
$access = 3;
$dbConnect = true;
require "../scripts/php/scriptSecurity.php";

// Partial name given by user.
$name = $_GET["name"];


if (!empty($name)){
    if (strpos($name, " ")){
        $nameParts = explode(" ", $name);
        if (strpos($nameParts[0], ",")) {
            $last = str_replace(",", "",$nameParts[0]);
            $first = $nameParts[1];
        }
        else {
            $first = $nameParts[0];
            $last = $nameParts[1];
        }
    } 
    else {
        $last = str_replace(",", "", $name); 
        $first = str_replace(",", "", $name);
    }

    // Freak out that maybe some hidden character is in the name. 
    $last = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9']/", "", $last );
    $first = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9']/", "", $first );

    if ($last != $first){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', ? , '%') AND FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%', ? , '%') ORDER BY LastName, FirstName LIMIT 30" ;
    }
    else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', ? , '%') OR FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%', ? , '%') ORDER BY LastName, FirstName LIMIT 30";
    }

    if ($nameStmt = $connect->prepare($query)){
        $nameStmt->bind_param('ss', $last, $first);

        if (!$nameStmt->execute()) {
            echo $nameStmt->error;
        }


        $result = $nameStmt->get_result();

        $count = 0;

        if (empty($result)){
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    $count++ ;
                    if ($count % 2 != 0) 
                        $class="odd";
                    else 
                        $class="even"; 
            ?>
                    <div class="studentRow <?php echo  $class ?>"><?php echo $row["LastName"] . ", " . $row["FirstName"] . " " . $row["MiddleName"] ?>  <div><a class="stuPass" id="stuPass_<?php echo $row["id"] ?>" href="scripts/getPass.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"] ?>">Pass</a></div><div><a class="stuDetails" id="stuDetails_ <?php $row["id"] ?>" href="scripts/students/getDetails.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"] ?>">Details</a></div></div>
                    <div class="stuDetails hidden" id="stuDetailsHolder_<?php echo $row["id"]?>"></div>
            <?php 
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "Results are empty.";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "<br />". $connect->error;
    }
}
```

Here is the code from uploading the data in the db. I was worried that I might have hidden characters lurking, but I think I have them all stripped out.

```
$fStu = new SplFileObject('../resources/students.txt');
$fStu->seek($count);
list($year,$building,$id,$last,$middle,$first,$gender,$grade,$gradYear) = explode(",",$fStu->current());    
    if (!empty($year)){
        $stuQuery = "INSERT INTO students (LastName, MiddleName, FirstName, StudentId, Gender, Grade, GradYear) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stuStmt = $connect->prepare($stuQuery);

        $last = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9']/", "", $last );
        $first = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9']/", "", $first );
        $middle = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9']/", "", $middle );
        $gender = preg_replace( "/\r|\n|\s+/", "", $gender );
        $id = intval(preg_replace('/\D/', '', $id));
        $gradYear = intval(preg_replace('/\D/','', $gradYear));
        $grade = intval(preg_replace('/\D/','', $grade));
        $stuStmt->bind_param("sssisss", $last, $middle, $first,$id,$gender,$grade,$gradYear);
        $stuStmt->execute();
        echo $count . "||" . $last . ", " . $first . " (" . $id . ")";
    }
    else {
        $count = -1;
        echo $count . "||Complete.";
    }
```

Here's the main page passing the partial name with the querystring.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#name").on("change paste keyup", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({url: "process/students.php?name=" + $("#name").val(), 
                    success: function(result){
                        $("#results").removeClass("hidden");
                        $("#results").html(result);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Here's a set of data getting uploaded.

```
> > Current School Year,Current Building,Student Id,Student Last Name,Student Middle Name,Student First Name,Student Gender,Student
> > Grade,Grad Year  2018,111,11111111111,Doe,Jane,,F,09,2021
> > 2018,111,22222222222,Doe,John,,M,09,2021
```

Comment: Why use `concat()` at all? Why not just attach the symbols to the variable before sending it through the query?

Comment: I tried that too (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138807/proper-pdo-syntax-for-parameterized-query-using-like-with-wildcards-ex). I think the outcome is the same, it's just where to append the wildcard right? Still the same issue.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the actual search term, with data contained in the database?

Comment: Always check the core documentation to avoid badly reimplementing things like [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php). Your stripping function only removes *one* of a carriage return, a newline or some spaces in one spot.

Comment: Ouch...tadman. I'll go back and review. Thanks for pointing that out. I'm just a teacher trying to write a site for my students, so this can be trying at times. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is tagged as PDO. If you really are using PDO and not mysqli then you cannot bind multiple parameters in a single statement as you are trying to. They should be declared individually and if you are using ? as placeholders they need to be numbered.

If you are using LIKE you must add the % signs to either side of the variable which you are going to bind, you cannot include them in your query as you are trying to.

As far as your query method, instead of trying to split your user input into first and last names why not concat the name fields from the database and search against the result of that instead?

`SELECT * FROM students WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', FirstName, LastName) LIKE '%whatever%';`